# Encode a string to be safe for html element fields

Tags: java, html, encoding

From client to server, my app correctly accepts text of any kind (I'm using prepared statements to stay safe on the database end).  When I display text from server to client I'm running into a problem now with text that has quotation marks, and perhaps there are other cases I haven't thought of or encountered yet.

```
label:"<%=myObj.getText()%>"
```

is being translated into:

```
label:""Hello World""
```

I think what I need is for the quotation marks in the data to be escaped like so:  \"

Is there a class that will do this encoding already so I don't have to write my own parser?

Searching through StackOverflow, I found a promising answer in java.net.URLEncoder that encodes special characters.  In reading through it's documentation, though, I found one translation I didn't want:

> The space character " " is converted into a plus sign "+".

Comment: I may have found it, or, rather, I may have found the right words to search StackOverflow under.   Apache commons has something for escaping html4 (close enough to 5, right?).  I haven't gotten it to compile yet in .jsp to verify it does the job. 
 I get the error message:Only a type can be imported. org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils resolves to a package

Comment: Gave up and wrote a string parser to look for quotation marks and replace them with quotation marks when displaying the data.  Expect to need to add additional characters to look out for in the future.